# How to UPDATE multiple same foreign key's value which is file type in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relation

I have a relation between project and file table like below:

```php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(File::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class File extends Model
{   
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }
}
```

I want to update in file table where foreign project_id is same and can update a single or multiple row together.
But only first file updated when use first() like following code:

```php
$files = $request->filenames;

if($files) {
    foreach ($files as $u_file) {
        $name=$u_file->getClientOriginalName();
        $u_file->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);
        $project_file =File::where('project_id', $id)->first();

        $project_file->filename = $name;
        $project->files()->save($project_file);
    }
}
```

by using get() instead of first() getting error like below:

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\xampp\tmp\php28ED.tmp

Comment: What is `upload_max_size` in `php.ini` file?

Comment: When you using get() method that will be retrieving all the files. And using first() it will return single records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `php.ini` file and update `upload_max_size`. Make sure upload_max_filesize is larger than file size(Uploaded file).

**When size changing following condition should be follow:**

```
- post_max_size must be larger than upload_max_filesize
- memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size
```